# Android decimal mask on EditText filled right to left

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I create a mask on an `EditText` that is filled from the right?

For example, the initial value is 0.0. Then if 1 is pressed it becomes 0.1, and then if I press 2, it becomes 1.2, up to 12.3 if the users presses 3 next.

Tried with libraries [like this](https://github.com/santalu/mask-edittext), but it doesn't allow the right to left filling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code I used, in case it helps someone else

```
class DecimalFormatter(private val txt: EditText): TextWatcher {
        var ignoreChanges = false

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
            if (!ignoreChanges) {
                ignoreChanges = true
                var content = txt.text.toString().replace(".", ",")
                var newContent = ""
                var commaFound = false
                for (c: Char in content) {
                    if ((c == ',' && !commaFound) || c != ',') {
                        newContent += c
                        if (c == ',') {
                            commaFound = true
                        }
                    }
                }
                txt.setText(newContent)
                if (newContent == "") {
                    newContent = "0,0"
                }

                txt.setSelection(txt.text.length)
                ignoreChanges = false
            }
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find [this library](https://github.com/faranjit/currency_edittext) useful. I checked the library and looks like this meets your expectation.

To include the library add the following in your `build.gradle` file.

```
implementation 'com.github.faranjit:currency-edittext:1.0.1'
```

Now use it like the following.

```
<faranjit.currency.edittext.CurrencyEditText
    android:id="@+id/edt_currency"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without library, just format output in `beforeTextChanged()`

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```